# Как получить содержимое тэга

Tags: jquery

При нажатии *reply*, нужно получить содержимое *user_to* в виде текста:

```js
function reply(x) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  i = $(x).parent('.text').children('.user_to').html();
  console.log(i);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='text another_user' onmouseover='reply_on(this)' onmouseout='reply_off(this)'>
  <div class='user_to'>".$row['user_from']."</div>
  <div class='user_to_text'>".$row['message_text']."</div>
  <div class='reply' onclick='reply()'>reply</div>
</div>"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы же знаете про то, что в вызове функции надо передавать туда параметры:

```
<div class='reply' onclick='reply(event, this)'>reply</div>

function reply(event, x) { 
  console.log($(x).closest('.text').find('.user_to').html()); 
}
```

Comment: а блин как же я забыл указать this , спасибо

Comment: @MiqayelPetrosyan Пожалуйста. Слева от ответа - знак "галочка".